# Sound problem with c++ video player

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I have a c++ made video player and for a reason I can't understand only some of the files (.avi) are playing with sound, the others only have the visual.

I think it's because these videos use a codec that the program doesn't support. Is there a way to "integrate" an other codec so all my avi files will have sound ?

Comment: What significance does the C++ have here?  Did you write it yourself in C++?

Comment: No I didn't write it myself, but I wanted to integrate the new codec in the c++ code (with openAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open them in VLC player and find the codec type of the audio, Check if your player supports that codec type. Adding the new codec type would depend on how your plug-able your video player code is

Answer (score 0):

Sure, run the codec's install program!